# Companies that provide user information / targeting API?

Tags: advertising, optimization

Are there any companies that provide simple APIs to get user information or targeting data on website visitors? Essentially some anonymous version of the data used by advertising companies to target ads. This could be a vector of 20 real number or something more intuitive.

I'd like to customize landing pages based on visitors' information, beyond what I can get from the request headers.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics [Website Optimizer API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gwo/commonTasks.html) I believe what you're looking for is the multivariate experiments.